# How to test if content is visible, not hidden by scroll bar in Capybara/Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, capybara

I have some code that updates what portion of a timeline is displayed at one time. So if you are looking at the time range from Jan 1st, 2013 thought Dec 31st, 2013, you have the ability to say I want all 12 months shown at once, or I only want 6 months shown (for example). If you choose the latter, then Jan - Jun are displayed and you must scroll the timeline right to view the remaining months.

I am attempting to test this with Selenium & Capybara. For each month, the corresponding abbreviation appears at the top of the timeline (Jan, Feb, etc.). For the case where all 12 months are displayed, I currently have this...

```
expected = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

for exp in expected do
  assert page.has_content?(exp), "Expected page to have #{exp}, it did not."
end
```

For the case where you choose to only display 6 months at a time, I tried to do the following:

```
expected = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun']
for exp in expected do
  assert page.has_content?(exp), "Expected page to have #{exp}, it did not."
end

not_expected = ['Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
for exp in not_expected do
  assert !page.has_content?(exp), "Expected page NOT to have #{exp}, but it did."
end
```

The problem is that the `not_expected` months, are still in the content of the page, they are just not visible. I looked into using `:visible => true` but had trouble figuring out how to use it. Additionally, the content is not being set to not be visible... It is just off the page. Is there any way to test this with Capybara/Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `find` command, instead of `page.has_content`?

You should be able to pass in the abbreviations you already use and Capybara should (by default) ignore anything it cannot see (for example, if it is off the screen).

There's also a setting you can use to ensure that Capybara ignores hidden elements, although I believe this is the default behaviour:

```
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
```

As an aside, I'd avoid using `!page.has_content?` anywhere in your tests as Capybara will wait for your default timeout to be reached before returning anything. There's a `page.has_no_content?` method that does just that and will return as soon as the content is not there, saving you valuable time.